# Map feature selection output to column name (ChiSqSelector)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select the most predictive features for a dataset...

```
label   features
class1  [2, 5.7, 3]
class1  [6, 3.2, 1]
...
```

...using [ChiSqSelector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-features.html#chisqselector) on Spark:

```
val selector = new ChiSqSelector()
  .setNumTopFeatures(10)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

val result = selector.fit(predictions).transform(predictions)
display(result)
```

When I do this, the output is simply the ranked column *values*:

```
selectedFeatures
[5.7, 3, 2]
[3.2, 1, 6]
...
```

However, I would to instead get the ranked column names... what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think `selector.fit(predictions).selectedFeatures()` gives you the selected column indices, although docs are lacking and I haven't tried it myself. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/ChiSqSelectorModel.html#selectedFeatures()

Comment: Ah, thats ChiSqSelectorModel (Mlib) instead of ChiSqSelector (ML), Ill give that one a go, cheers